# Exporting raster from R changes the scale of extent

Tags: qgis, raster, rasterization, terra

I have converted a shapefile to a raster in R using both terra and raster packages.  When I export the raster and try to open it in QGIS the scale has shrunk making the whole shapefile only 1 m across when it is many km in size in reality.  This also sometimes happens within R (see pic).  The second QGIS pic is the shapefile before importing to R to convert to raster.

I have experimented with exporting using terra or raster and including the CRS of 27700 or not when importing the shapefile.This process works fine with some of my other shapefiles of the same area that have less polygons.

I can't use QGIS to rasterize the shapefile because it doesn't work (just produces a nonsense raster of huge values) and I also have a huge batch of shapefiles that I need to rasterize.

WHy would a raster change its dimensions so drastically and what can I do to prevent this happening?

[image]
[image]

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't the best of problem statements. Please [Edit] the Question to focus on what you tried (all the steps)  and the problem uncountered.

Comment: In the several years of the raster libraries existence, and now terra, I have never seen anything like this. Since you do not document your workflow in R there is no way for us to troubleshoot. I would imagine that where things are going amiss is in the reference raster that you are using for rasterization. It should represent the extent, dimensions, resolution and projection thus, acting as a templet for vector conversion. The extent and projection should match the input vector object. We need to see your R code and description of the resulting  objects.